# Prometheus + Grafana, incorrect timestamp difference

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a metric in prometheus called: whatsapp_engine_last_dlr_timestamp with a label called event_name (metaX). When I put the metric last_timestamp  in Grafana query and select a Gauge graph, it brings me the correct information per each label. Example:

[image]

But, when I do time() - last_timestamp  it did not bring correctly for all labels, only for the first one. Example:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz2jR.png]

Any ideia how to do that in a single query?